# How to create the ultimate jquery-script for tracking outbound links in Google Analytics?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics, tracking, outbound

I found some jquery scripts to deal with tracking outbound links  in Google Analytics.

But they all seem to have some flaws:

- http://iso-100.com/blog/post/updated-script-for-tracking-outbound-links-in-google-analytics-with-jquery/
  **Disadvantages:** Uses trackPageView and does not contain a "setTimeOut"-function as suggested by Google: 
  http://www.google.com/support/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55527
- http://blog.rebeccamurphey.com/2008/12/04/update-tracking-outbound-clicks-with-google-analytics-and-jquery/ 
  **Disadvantages:** does not contain a "setTimeOut"-function and is not very efficient, because it binds the click-event to all links in the document.

So I am looking for the ultimate jQuery-Script to track outbound links in Google Analytics.

Comment: Why don't you try rolling your own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it here:
https://github.com/christianhellsten/jquery-google-analytics

- directly includes Google Analytics Code
- Has good configuration options
- not only tracks external links, but can also be used for other events like "mouseover"